# connect function fails because the signal cannot find the object

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-signals

When calling `QObject::connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal, const QObject *receiver, const char *method, Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)`, I get the error "cannot call a member funtion without object*".

I'm trying to connect a signal emit by a custom button to a slot defined in the container class of the button.
In the container i define:

```
    signals:
        void hovered();
```

In the container header, I define an object of `customButton` class:

```
customButton* casilla = new customButton;
```

And the slot like:

```
    public slots:
        void mostrarCasilla();
```

Now, in the container constructor, I try to connect the signal and the slot with this line

```
QObject::connect(casilla,&customButton::hovered(),this,&board::mostrarCasilla());
```

I think is some kind of simple mistake, I'll put the full code to give an example for the community if I make it work

Comment: `&customButton::hovered()` --> `&customButton::hovered`?  Similarly, remove the `()` from the slot definition.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand better how this function works

Answer (score 2):

`&A::func` is a member function pointer, the role of `&` is fetch the address of func.

for `func()`, `()` is a function call, perhaps you can get a value after `func()`, but this value is r-value, `&` need a l-value, so `&A::func()` is wrong in any situation.

Comment: thank you very much, now I understand better how this function works

Comment: Nitpick - `&A::func()` is wrong in any situation, where `func` is a non-static member function of class A. Otherwise the expression may got other meanings (e.g. taking address for result of call `operator()`, etc.)